# What test to use with non nested regressions?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I have estimated several regressions on different samples. For example, I have estimated these regressions:
$$
y = a_1 + b_1 x_1 + c_1 z + e_1 \\
y = a_2 + b_2 x_2 + c_2 z + e_2 \\
y = a_3 + b_3 x_3 + c_3 z + e_3 \\
y = a_4 + b_4 x_4 + c_4 z + e_4 \\
y = a_5 + b_5 x_5 + c_5 z + e_5
$$
$z$ is just a control variable, but notice that each $x$ is different in each regression. These are non nested models. This may be a long shot, but is there a test I can use for $H_0: b_1 = b_2 = b_3 = b_4 = b_5$?

Comment: Can you not do a omnibus F test? Compare the fit of $y=a+cz+e$ against $y=a+b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + \ldots + b_5 x_5 + e$. The null in this test is all $b_i=0$. Alternaitve is at least one $b_i \neq 0$

Comment: The regressions are on different samples.

Comment: Ah I see. You could just compare the confidence intervals of each $b_i$. If a pair of intervals do not overlap this implies a significant difference. You may want to adjust the CIs to account for multiple comparisons

Comment: Ah I see. That's good idea. By correction you mean something like Bonferroni or Sidak?

Comment: Something like that would help, so if you want $\alpha=0.05$ use one of those corrections to find a new alpha and construct the corresponding CIs at the new alpha

Comment: Can these correction procedures be used to test $H_0: b_i = b_j$, rather than $H_0: b_i = b_j = 0$?

Comment: Sure. Recall that a confidence interval is essentially a set of plausible values for a parameter. If two intervals overlap this suggests that the two parameters _may_ have the same value. I'm not sure about the exact error rates of this type of test anyway (search this site/ask a new Q). And this test is more conservative than a "normal" hypothesis testing procedure. Two non-overlapping $95\%$ CIs implies $p<<0.05$.

Comment: I was thinking that I can test $H_0: b_i = b_j = c$ for given $c$, and then integrate over $c$ wrt the joint distribution of $b_1, ..., b_5$?

Comment: Just posted a new question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/578602/how-to-test-if-coefficients-are-equal-to-each-other-with-non-nested-regressions