# How to test if coefficients are equal to each other with non-nested regressions?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I have the p-values, 95% confidence intervals, standard errors and coefficients of $b_i$ in the following regressions, which are estimated on different samples:
$$
y = a_1 + b_1 x_1 + c_1 z + e_1 \\
y = a_2 + b_2 x_2 + c_2 z + e_2 \\
y = a_3 + b_3 x_3 + c_3 z + e_3 \\
y = a_4 + b_4 x_4 + c_4 z + e_4 \\
y = a_5 + b_5 x_5 + c_5 z + e_5
$$
Notice that for each regression, the $x$ regressor is different. How can I test that $b_i = b_j$? As indicated in a [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/578196/what-test-to-use-with-non-nested-regressions), I can use information on whether the CI overlap each other, but I do not know how to implement that. To complicate things, these standard errors and CIs come from bootstrapping, since in my application, the distribution of each $b_i$ is not known.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say $x$ are different, do you mean that they are different variables or just different samples?

Comment: Different variables. but also each regression is run on a different sample.

Comment: Different sample of $y$?

Comment: $y$ is the same outcome variable, but each regression is in a different sample, so yes.

Comment: okay. one last question: for a given sample of $y$, do you not have measures of at least two of $x_i$? If not, is it a because data is not available (i.e. in the true data generating process all $x_i$ contribute but just not recorded) or that systematically variable $x_i$ has undergone a change and become a new variable (i.e., in the true data generating process only one variable is influencing $y$)?

Comment: I'd say that each $x_i$ is a different variable. For example, imagine that each sample is a corresponds to a different set of countries, and each $x_i$ is a binary variable that is 1 if the country has gone to war 1 time in reg 1, two times in reg 2, etc (perhaps this is not a very good example, my data is more complicated). What do you have in mind?

Comment: Each variable is different that you have already mentioned. Point is whether a given $y$ is function of, say, both $x_1, x_2$ but you only have data for $x_1$. From your example it doesn't seem so. In your example variable is actually same but you just need to include relevant dummy variables.

Comment: Hmm, in my data, if I know $x_i$, I already know all the other $x_j$. They form a mutually exclusive set of dummies. Each sample $i$ is constructed so that $x_i = 1$ for some observations, but all the other $x_j = 0$ for all observations in sample $i$.

Comment: In that case if you have n countries you need n-1 dummies. Say coefficient for dummy $i, j$ are zero (insignificant). Then they are same. If not then use restricted model approach.

Comment: Restricted model approach? as in an F-test?

Comment: Yes. Because now your models are nested.

Comment: But I cannot run them together. Is there a way around it? A way to test the hypothesis the the results I already have.

Comment: You can. Read more about how dummy variables work and why one less is used.

Comment: I cannot pool these samples together. They are located in different machines.

Comment: That makes it interesting. I think you can cleverly use matrix algebra to merge the results and do a combined regression calculation. Will think about it and if I get somewhere will post it here.